# How to listen for battery charging state changes in Android with targetSdkVersion > 25

Tags: android

With targetSdkVersion <= 25 one can listen for battery charging state changes using a BroadcastReceiver with an implicit intent, declaring these as such in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

(see [Monitoring changes in charging state](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring#MonitorChargeState))

However, now with the ban on implicit broadcast intents (besides some [notable exceptions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions)) for targetSdkVersion > 25, this throws a warning (`W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent`) and does not execute the intent.

There is a way to use [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler) to schedule a job that only executes when the [phone enters charging state](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setRequiresCharging(boolean)), but how can we efficiently listen for when the power is disconnected? The only idea I could come up with is to use an AlarmManager to periodically poll the battery charging state.

Comment: Wont starting a service with a broadcast receiver that listens for these broadcasts solve the issue?

Comment: @tyczj - unfortunately, the service will eventually go in the background and you must eventually also unregister the broadcast receiver.

Comment: that's why you use a foreground service, that does not have the restrictions that a normal service does

Comment: @tyczj - I don't want to have to make the user suffer with a sticky notification just for a battery charging state service

Comment: So instead you want to make the user suffer with constant polling that they may or may not know about eating up their battery? (which still wont work BTW)